# Set height and width of controls wihtin window size wpf

Tags: wpf

I have a following xaml file

```
<Window x:Class="NodeXL_Graph_Drawer.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Technewlogic.Samples.WpfModalDialog"                      
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
Title="NodeXL Graph" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Smrf.NodeXL.Visualization.Wpf;assembly=Smrf.NodeXL.Control.Wpf" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="ModalDialogParent" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="col1"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" >
            <my:NodeXLControl Name="nodeXLControl1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  EdgeSelectedColor="Red" VertexSelectedColor="Red" ShowVertexToolTips="True" VertexClick="nodeXLControl1_VertexClick" SelectionChanged="nodeXLControl1_SelectionChanged" MouseMode="Select" MouseAlsoSelectsIncidentEdges="False" ContextMenuOpening="nodeXLControl1_ContextMenuOpening" GraphLaidOut="nodeXLControl1_GraphLaidOut">

            </my:NodeXLControl>
        </StackPanel>
        <!--<ComboBox Height="23" Margin="39,12,119,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="comboBox1_SelectionChanged" />-->
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="2">                
            <toolkit:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="0,62,0,0" Name="grdGraphDetails" ItemsSource="{Binding GraphDetail}" IsReadOnly="True" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="109" MouseLeftButtonUp="grdGraphDetails_MouseLeftButtonUp" 
                          SelectedValuePath="Key" Height="179" />              
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
    <controls:ModalDialog x:Name="ModalDialog"></controls:ModalDialog>         
    <controls:ModalDialog1 x:Name="ModalDialog1"></controls:ModalDialog1>
</Grid>
```

Here i have two controls NodeXlControl1 and Datagrid1 on page seprated by grid seprator. when window loads NodeXlControl1 does not come within the grid column width and height. i want nodexlcontrol1 should be shown with in the grid column width and height. and i if it goes beyond the limits of width and height of column, scroll bar should come.

Comment: It would be nice if you would only post the code parts related to the problem. e.g. `<my:NodeXLControl.ContextMenu>` is totally needless.

Comment: does the NodeXLControl have a built in ScrollViewer? Otherwise how should your controls know that you want that behavior? Wrap the NodeXLControl inside a ScrollViewer and, depending on how the control works, it should work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If your `my:NodeXLControl` internally has some scroll viewer (like some `ItemsControl` or `ScrollViewer` based child) then simply wrapping `my:NodeXLControl` in a `Grid` would do the trick.

`StackPanel` expands to overflow the children. `Grid` expands to outer's container's availability of space.

```
<Grid>
    <my:NodeXLControl  ... />
```

Should do the trick.

But if you `my:NodeXLControl` has no scroll viewer in it then you would need to wrap it inside one and provide `absolute` width or height to it or wrap it inside a `Grid` for it to bound to its avilable space and show scrollbars accordingly.

e.g.

```
   <Grid>
      <ScrollViewer ...>
        <my:NodeXLControl ...>
```

Comment: Can i get the grid column width and height on window load ??

Comment: Nopes. Grid is not designed to be like that. If you have done a proper panel layout the `Grid` would accommodate as per the parent container's size.